# Slick Carousel and Slick lightbox on same element

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have a slider for which Im using slick carousel, and then I need a lightbox on these images for slick lightbox.

My code:

```
<ul class="gallery-slider">
   <?php foreach($gallery as $image) : ?>
    <li>
      <a href="image-url-here">
        <img src="image-url-here">
      </a>                         
    </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

$('.gallery-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots: false,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1000,
                settings: {
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    arrows: false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 700,
                settings: {
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
                    arrows: false
                }
            }
            // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
            // settings: "unslick"
            // instead of a settings object
        ]
    });

$('.gallery-slider').slickLightbox({
        itemSelector: '> li > a'
    });
```

When I click on one of the images, it just opens the image in a new tab rather than using the lightbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this myself, so added an answer.

This was because when slick is initialised, it adds extra divs to the markup.

So I need to make the `slickLightbox()` selector a bit deeper like:

```
$('.gallery-slider').slickLightbox({
    itemSelector: '> div > div > div > a'
});
```